# How can some clouds be removed from the sky?

Tags: photovoltaics, evaporation

I order to optimize output from a solar park I need to know how to remove clouds in the sky in an economically feasible way. Output improves tenfold without clouds. How can that be achieved? Weather is apparently [modifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_modification).

Some techniques, like adding or removing material nucleation particles, are too demanding.

Techniques are apparently efficient enough to be prohibited in international regulations, like [ENMOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_Modification_Convention).

Cloud conditions are not trivial. [NASA writes on the subject](https://climatekids.nasa.gov/cloud-formation/#:%7E:text=Although%20the%20basic%20idea%20of%20cloud%20formation%20is%20easy%20to%20understand%2C%20there%20is%20much%20more%20to%20learn.%20Peek%20beneath%20a%20cloud%E2%80%99s%20fluffy%20exterior%2C%20and%20you%E2%80%99ll%20find%20a%20world%20of%20complexity.%20In%20fact%2C%20clouds%20are%20considered%20one%20of%20the%20most%20challenging%20aspects%20of%20climate%20science.):

> Although the basic idea of cloud formation is easy to understand, there is much more to learn. Peek beneath a cloud’s fluffy exterior, and you’ll find a world of complexity. In fact, clouds are considered one of the most challenging aspects of climate science.

It is thus not possible to conclude that clouds cannot be easily removed.

Svensmark et al. mentions a connection between ionization and cloud changes:

> Svensmark, H., Svensmark, J., Enghoff, M.B. et al.
> Atmospheric ionization and cloud radiative forcing.
> Sci Rep 11, 19668 (2021).
> https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-99033-1

I am especially interested in modifying the conditions determining the aerosol size in the cloud.

Comment: Reduce particulate emissions that add to cloud formation.

Comment: Rural environments have no emissions? BS … those particulate emissions travel on the wind.

Comment: You don't *need* to know this, you aren't going to go out and do it.

Comment: How do you affect things that have mass? Under what conditions will the energy you use doing so be worth the gains on your solar setup?

Comment: There is simply no practical way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Sell the clouds on Ebay. Winning bidder is responsible for arranging transport.

Comment: If you read the article you link to, you will know that it describes unsuccessful attempts to modify weather. Cloud seeding is partially successful, but in general it only causes rain to fall in one region & not where it was going to fall. Clouds that form overcast skies are generally part of very large weather systems & the only thing that is going to be moving them are the forces of nature. You need to learn patience & just wait it out.

Answer (score 1):

Work out which way the wind usually blows where you are.  Build a large mountain range between you and the sea in that direction.

Most of the rain clouds will drop their rain onto the mountains, leaving you with fewer clouds.

Comment: How will you get planning permission for mountains?

Comment: @SolarMike Maybe you can promise the people in the planning commission free skiing passes to the resort you're building on the mountains!

Comment: @Chris_abc no way planning would be given for a bribe like that - sarcasm mode off... or on...

Comment: Please only give realistic answers or none. Your answer is not realistic since the solution is supposed to be economically feasible. This is implied in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking hypothetically... you could make the mirrors sufficiently steerable to aim reflected sunlight at the pesky clouds, raising their temperature and vaporizing the water droplets.  But that won't work if the cloud cover is complete. Then you'd best use a few hydrogen bombs to do the trick.

If the neighbors raise objections to this plan, you could instead deploy an *air-fuel explosive*, where a cargo plane full of gasoline sprays out the gasoline while flying through the cloud and then ignites the resulting air/fuel mixture.

Comment: Please only give realistic answers or none. Your answer is not realistic since the solution is supposed to be economically feasible. This is implied in the question.

Comment: @DavidJonsson, the question itself was manifestly unrealistic. In answering as I did, I was implying this. Let me know if you wish for it to be deleted.

Comment: It is not well shown that the question is unrealistic. I will update the question later. Your answer is not in line with how Stack Exchange is supposed to work.